# Identify Certificate Authority from public key

Tags: openssl

Under OS X, the `/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem` contains many certificates in this format:

```
----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
 <...snip..>
----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

In Ubuntu, in `/etc/ssl/certs`, each certificate is in its own file; with the files named like `Visa_eCommerce_Root.pem`, `Swisscom_Root_CA_1.pem` etc.

I was wondering if on OS X there is a way I can get similar names for each certificate contained in the `cert.pem` file?

PS. The context is that I am trying to debug an issue on OS X where some SSL connections fail, but when I import all the .pem files from Ubuntu into OS X, the SSL connection works. I wanted to identify which certificate is missing on OS X.

Comment: Try to explode the PEM bundle in to separate PEM files with the [method I listed for a different question.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108517/should-i-be-concerned-that-google-no-longer-trusts-specific-symantec-root-ca-cer) And then just grep over the files.

Answer (score 1):

In OS X you can inspect all the system root certificates by doing the following:

1. Press `cmd + spacebar` and then type "keychain access" followed by `return`.
2. Select "System Roots" and "Certificates" in the left side pane.

You should now see all the root certs installed and used by OS X e.g.

[image]

You should be able to compare this list to the list of certs installed on your Ubuntu box.

PS: You can parse the `cert.pem` certificate via `openssl x509 -text -noout < /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem`. This won't give you a list of roots though, just a single cert (whose purpose I am unsure of).

Comment: `just a single cert (whose purpose I am unsure of).` It's just the first cert in the bundle. Nothing special about it. OpenSSL is peculiar that way.

Comment: If you want to explode the pem-bundle into individual members, you can you use my [small bash script from a previous answer.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108517/should-i-be-concerned-that-google-no-longer-trusts-specific-symantec-root-ca-cer)